# Add shortcode in my div

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to add a shortcode in a div created by me in my theme

This is the div:

```
    <?php if(!is_home()): ?>

          <div id="cristi"><?php echo get_the_content(1); ?></div> 

   <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the shortcode:

```
[contact-form-7 id="54" title="Contact form 1"]
```

This is the link:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/?page_id=19

Just look at this moment ...

What needs to change to run this shortcode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps better suited to StackExchange Wordpress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

To answer the question, you can use do_shortcode: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

```
<?php if(!is_home()): ?>

  <div id="cristi"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="54" title="Contact form 1"]' ) ?></div> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: nice link and its very useful @Jonathan